# Repeating the n-index of array in a table view in swift 4.2

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview

This is a part of my code:

```
let array = ["a","b","c"]

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return array.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    let someWord = array[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

How can I display n-index one more time?
For example: "a", "b", "c", "a"
or "a", "b", "c", "c".

Thank you!

Comment: Modify `array` in order to have what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to modify your original array, you can create a second array to note which ones to repeat:

```
let array = ["a","b","c"]

// indices of array to repeat - 2 will repeat "c"
var repeats = [2]

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // Number of cells in the table is the sum of the counts of both arrays
    return array.count + repeats.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

    let someWord: String

    // Get the proper item from the array
    if indexPath.row < array.count {
        someWord = array[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        someWord = array[repeats[indexPath.row - array.count]]
    }

    // Do something with someWord

    return cell
}
```

---

**Notes:**

1. Anytime you modify the `repeats` array, reload your `tableView`.
2. If you don't want to repeat any items, set `repeats = []`.
3. The array allows you to repeat multiple items, or a single item multiple times:  To get `"a", "b", "c", "a", "a", "a"`, set repeats to `[0, 0, 0]`.

Answer (score 0):

For the sequences:

["a", "b", "c"],  ["a", "b", "c"],  ["a", "b", "c"] etc.

or reversed

["a", "b", "c"],  ["c", "b", "a"],  ["a", "b", "c"] etc.

```
let repeateCount = 4
let reverse = false
let array = ["a","b","c"]

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return array.count * repeateCount
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    var index = indexPath.row % array.count
    if reverse {
        if (indexPath.row / array.count) % 2 != 0 { // odd
            index = array.count - index - 1
        }
    }
    let someWord = array[index]
    return cell
}
```